# Windows Remote Desktop ending immediately

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, remote-desktop

I am trying to access a machine running Ubuntu from my Windows machine.

I can already access it with SSH using SuperPutty with no problem.

I have already installed xrdp in the ubuntu machine.
`sudo apt install xrdp`

however whenever I try to access it from my windows 10 machine with Remote Desktop it promtps me to put my id and password and then the first screen appears but then it goes back to Remote Desktop first window. In other words it throws me out from the session.

On the windows side I have checked in System-> Remote settings -> Remote (as in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_IbWKuWFyc) and I found that I didn't allow remote connections to my windows computer. So I changed that to "allow remote connections"

However I still cannot access the remote desktop. Any ideas on how to proceed?